# Refresh div with mySql result

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm using this ajax simple code for refresh a div with mySql result.
Work, but it's a correct way?
For few connections it's ok but for a lot of connections....?

```
setInterval(function(){ 
 $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "current_number.php",
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {           
          $("#current_number").html(""+data+"");
        }
    });
 }, 500);
```

thanks

Comment: The ajax code doesn't affect how many connections you could have on the server  since it runs in each user's browser.

Comment: if thats an issue, you will need to scale your mysql server. you can have web server on one server and database on a separate server.

Comment: With setInterval there is a connection with mySql through php page once 0,5 second. There is not probability to down server?

Comment: try $('#current_number').load(' #current_number'); in your success function.